# Excel Highlighting current time cell

Tags: excel, time, conditional-formatting

I'm designing a time schedule on MS Excel (or Google Sheets).
I'd like it to highlight the cell that contains the time which falls within half an hour before the current time.
Is there a way to do that?
What I did is:

```
A1= now()
A2= now()+time(0,30,0)
```

Cells A3:A33 contain times I manually typed with an interval of 30 minutes between each, *e.g. A3=07:00, A4=07:30, ... , A32= 23:30.*
And I applied conditional formatting to cells A3:A33 as follows:

```
If the value is between A1 and A2, then highlight the cells.
```

But nothing seems to change.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you formatted the cells with the date / time type?

Comment: Excel doesn't know that 07:00 is actually 19 December 2017 07:00:00, which is what NOW() would give you. Your times must be formatted the same as each other if you're going to compare them. To check formatting, you can set the cells to general and get a number rather than a date.

Comment: Thank you.   All the time cells have the same time formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `NOW` is not only current time but current date plus current time. So if the other cells contains the time only, do using

`=TIME(HOUR(NOW()),MINUTE(NOW()),SECOND(NOW()))` in `A1`

and

`=A1+TIME(0,30,0)` in `A2`.

Then `A1`will contain current time only and `A2` will contain current time plus 30 minutes.

In **Conditional Formatting** use:

...between `$A$1` and `$A$2`

Comment: Thanx, but this didn't work. Now what is getting highlighted is 08:30 instead of 22:00.

Comment: This is tested and works for me. What results are you getting in `A1` and `A2`?

Comment: Of course you need fixating the `$A$1` and `$A$2` within the conditional formatting. When used `A1` and `A2`, the reference will be changed from cell to cell in CF. So use: ...between `$A$1` and `$A$2`.

Comment: Oh, I've missed that point! Now it works perfectly. Thanks a lot.